# Bootstrap float left automatically in a nav menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, menu, grid

Good day.  I have this code for my menu:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>

            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 5</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 6</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 7</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 8</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 9</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>


        </body>
    </html>
```

When you resize the windows, you can see, that the right entry 'Login' and 'Sign in' do a wordwrap (because there is no space anymore) and **stay to the right**.  Is there a CSS way (without javascript) to let them move to the left like the other entries?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  
<div class="container">
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
  <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This Will Sort Out Your Problem

Or You can Learn More About This in [click The Link Below For Know More](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp)

Comment: what happend between the screen size 769px to 984px

Comment: It is the same like mine, just with 3 entries, instead of 9. This will not solve my problem.